# Is recursiveness always from bottom to top?

Tags: recursion

Lets assume `dir a` has `dir b` which has `dir c`.
In a recursive deletion of these directories we can't "just delete" `dir a`. We must first delete `dir c` (and any file it has, if it has), then `dir b` (and any file it has, if it has) and only then could we delete `dir a`.

This seems to me "from bottom to top", time and again.
Is recursiveness always from bottom to top?

Comment: an easy counter example is creating those directories : you first need to create `dir a` to be able to create `dir b`, etc.

Comment: @AloisChristen if I understand you correctly, this is an easy counter example for recursiveness from top to bottom (opposite direction).

Comment: I think I should read about "head recursion" and "tail recursion".